# Extend Prototype method with wrap() but class isn't accessible

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypejs, extend

I have a site with a prototype class created in a file called `calculator.js`, containing the following code:

```
    !function() {

    var LoanCalculator = Class.create({
        initialize: function() {},

        exampleMethod: function(value) {
            console.log(value);
        }
    }
```

In a separate file **example.js** I'm trying to extend the class and rewrite the `exampleMethod` using`wrap()`:

```
LoanCalculator.exampleMethod = LoanCalculator.exampleMethod.wrap(function (parentMethod, value) {
    return parentMethod(value);
});
```

This all seems correct however all I get is:

> LoanCalculator is not defined

I'm certain that this is a scoping issue as the class is created in `!function() {` but I'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: Is your call to `wrap` inside the same function as your `LoanCaclulator` declaration? If not, move them into the same function. (If you can't do that for some reason, why is `LoanCaclulator` in its own function?)

Comment: Your `var LoanCalculator` is in the wrong scope. And it seems you're not even calling that function in where you defined it; was this supposed to be an IIFE?

Comment: managed to get it working, but only if it’s in the php file and uses the initialised instance of the class rather than rewriting the base class.

Comment: The function is invoked on the php file. I can't edit the calculator.js file

Comment: I think the way the class was created has made it hard to extend as it's not been scoped very well. I thought there may be a more elegant way around it but there doesn't seem to be.